# WPF DateTimePicker user control

Tags: c#, datetime, wpf, xaml, databinding

I've created a `UserControl` that should act as a control inside a `Window`:

**XAML:**

```xaml
    <UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.UserControls.DateTimePicker"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Converters"
             x:Name="dtp">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:NullDateTimeConverter x:Key="nullDateTimeConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDateTime,
                                ElementName=dtp,
                                Converter={StaticResource nullDateTimeConverter},
                                StringFormat={}{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm},
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Width="50"
                BorderBrush="Orange"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Command="{Binding ChangePopupStatusCommand}"
                Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}">
            <Rectangle Width="20"
                       Height="20"
                       Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button},
                                      Path=Foreground}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_calendar}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </Button>

        <Popup Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Width="400"
               IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}"
               PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RepeatButton Command="{Binding ChangeTimeCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="addHour"
                                  Content="+" />
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Column="1"
                                  Command="{Binding ChangeTimeCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="addMinute"
                                  Content="+" />
                    <TextBox
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBox.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat=" {0:D2}:{1:D2}">
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="SelectedDateTime.Hour" />
                                <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="SelectedDateTime.Minute" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBox.Text>
                    </TextBox>
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2"
                                  Command="{Binding ChangeTimeCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="subHour"
                                  Content="-" />
                    <!--  Click="SubHours_Click"  -->
                    <RepeatButton Grid.Row="2"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Command="{Binding ChangeTimeCommand}"
                                  CommandParameter="subMinute"
                                  Content="-" />
                </Grid>
                <Calendar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                          SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDateTime,
                                                 ElementName=dtp,
                                                 Converter={StaticResource nullDateTimeConverter}}"
                          Style="{StaticResource styleCalendar}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**XAML.CS**

```cs
public partial class DateTimePicker : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTimePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    #region SelectedTime

    public DateTime? SelectedDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime?)GetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedDateTimeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty 
        SelectedDateTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDateTime",
        typeof(DateTime?),
        typeof(DateTimePicker));

    #endregion

    private bool _isPopupOpen;
    public bool IsPopupOpen
    {
        get { return _isPopupOpen; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isPopupOpen, value);
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val,
       [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(member, val)) return;

        member = val;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged

    #region ChangePopup Command
    private CommandBase _changePopupStatusCommand;
    public CommandBase ChangePopupStatusCommand
    {
        get { return _changePopupStatusCommand ?? (_changePopupStatusCommand = new CommandBase(ChangePopupStatus)); }
    }
    private void ChangePopupStatus(object obj)
    {
        IsPopupOpen = !IsPopupOpen;
    }
    #endregion

    #region ChangeTime Command
    private CommandBase _chageTimeCommand;
    public CommandBase ChangeTimeCommand
    {
        get { return _chageTimeCommand ?? (_chageTimeCommand = new CommandBase(ChangeTime)); }
    }
    private void ChangeTime(object obj)
    {
        if (!SelectedDateTime.HasValue)
            SelectedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        switch (obj.ToString())
        {
            case "addHour":
                SelectedDateTime = SelectedDateTime.Value.AddHours(1);
                break;
            case "addMinute":
                SelectedDateTime = SelectedDateTime.Value.AddMinutes(1);
                break;
            case "subHour":
                SelectedDateTime = SelectedDateTime.Value.AddHours(-1);
                break;
            case "subMinute":
                SelectedDateTime = SelectedDateTime.Value.AddMinutes(-1);
                break;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**`NullDateTimeConverter`:**

```cs
public class NullDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (Nullable<DateTime>)value;

        if (val.HasValue && val.Value > DateTime.MinValue)
            return val;

        return String.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = value.ToString();
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        return DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime) ? resultDateTime : value;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```xaml
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Calibration Due" />
    <uc:DateTimePicker SelectedDateTime="{Binding CalibarationDue, 
                Mode=TwoWay, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DockPanel>
```

The thing I'm most unsure of is the way I use the `binding` in side my picker. Any comments or suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest building a custom control. user control's though can accomplish the same result's are conventionally used to group existing elements with no logic.  further more using a custom control will enable you to switch the control template with something else. and refer to your control with TemplateBinding from within it's template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used two types of bindings:

**1. Binding between your control and the usage DataContext**

This binding is fine and is the way how WPF binding system was supposed to work with respect to the MVVM pattern.

**2. Bindings between xaml controls and the xaml class (Same class which is the parent of those controls)**

The interactions between xaml controls and xaml code-behind are not supposed to flow through the same MVVM pattern. This is why in the partial class you have the possibility to access directly your controls.

Example from xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Width="50"
            BorderBrush="Orange"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Name="ButtonChangeStatus"
            Click="ButtonChangeStatus_OnClick"
            Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}">
```

Example from code-behind:

```
void ButtonChangeStatus_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsPopupOpen = !IsPopupOpen;
    ButtonChangeStatus.Background = Brushes.Green;
}
```

Another drawback could be the usage of some properties from outside of your implementation. Suppose there is some logic which needs to open the popup without a click on the `ButtonChangeStatus` button but from a click which originates outside of your implementation. To achieve such behavior the user of your control would need to bind `IsOpen` to his `DataContext`. But in the current implementation it's not possible without a great confusion (you need to have two `IsOpen` dependency properties); it will be possible by exposing the `IsOpen` dependency property to the outside ViewModel in the same way as you already did with `SelectedDateTime`. Having both a local `IsOpen` property and a dependency one will allow you to handle the `Popup` using two sources.